# Decrease calculation time of NDSolve for coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Hi Stackexchange community,

I am rather new to Mathematica, especially when it comes to dealing with numerical stuff. Right now I am trying to numerically solve a system of two coupled differential equations for certain sets of values. The system is the following:

```
    modp = 
{D[r[t]*Cos[ϕ[t]], {t, 2}] == w1*D[r[t]*Sin[ϕ[t]], t] - w2*Cos[w1*t]*Sin[ϕ[t]],
 D[r[t]*Sin[ϕ[t]], {t, 2}] == -w1*D[r[t]*Cos[ϕ[t]], t] - w2*Cos[w1*t]*Cos[ϕ[t]]};
```

For the values

```
v0 = 7.5*10^7;
w1 = 1.52*10^10;
w2 = 1.59*10^(-11);
```

Mathematica is able to solve these differential equations numerically. But for the values

```
v0 = 7.5*10^7;
w1 = 1.52*10^10;
w2 = 0.437;
```

I get the message

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 2.879453677024192`*^-7.

Now, I know that the maximum number of steps can be increased by the MaxSteps-command but if I increase the steps by a factor of 10, the same warning occurs for a time that is a factor of 10 higher than the previous one:

```
dglmodphotp = NDSolve[
  {modp, r[0] == v0/w1, ϕ[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, ϕ'[0] == -v0/r[0]},
  {r[t], ϕ[t]}, {t, 0, Pi*10^7}, MaxSteps -> 100000]
```

> Maximum number of 100000 steps reached at the point t == 
>   2.843461540218415`*^-6.

So in order to solve the System of ODE for this time intervall I have to increase the maximum number of steps by a factor of 10^14 which (how I see it) roughly also increases the calculation time by this factor. Is there another possibility to solve this system which is not that time-comsuming ?

EDIT: The value of v0 is 7.5*10^7.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you give the value of `v0` you are using?
Your very large `w1` means that the $sin$ and $cos$ terms are oscillating wildly with a period of $10^{-10}$, and then you are trying to integrate up to $10^7$. On my system it claims to integrate, but the results don't actually satisfy the ODEs.

Comment: Same observations as @KraZug. Maybe the w1 should be  `w1 = 1.52*10^(-10) ` ?

Comment: Hi, I edited the value of v0 to be 7.5*10^7. The value of w1 is correct. The ODE system describes the Motion of an electron due to the Lorentz force law plus a small modification. The frequency w1 is e*B/m with the elemental charge e, the magnetic field B and the electron mass m. For a magnetic field of B=0.08 Tesla (it has to have this value) i get this large value of w1.

Comment: Then it should be no surprise that you need a mammoth number of steps to integrate to such a large value of $t$ - the underlying functions are oscillating with such a short timestep and then you are trying to go to huge time. More worrying to me is that the solutions I'm getting out are not consistent with the input equations.

Comment: To follow up on what @KraZug has mentioned, could you rescale things so that your numbers are more reasonable and less wildly oscillatory? As long as you did it in some consistent, intelligent way I expect you could back the target result out.

Comment: Also, can I check that the equations are correct, with `Cos[w1 t]` in both?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, one could rescale t -> w1*t but the same warning occurs then for a time that is w1 times the original one where the first warning occured. So I don't think that rescaling changes matter.

Comment: @KraZug Yes, both equations are correct.

Comment: Something is terribly wrong with your parameters. Assuming t is in units of seconds, which is the usual is most systems of units, why do you want to integrate up to 363,61 days, realy days!!??

Comment: @akku14 The calculation is part of my master thesis and I want to calculate an effect which is very small. The setup is an electron in a magnetic field and for typical time intervalls like hours or days the effect would not be measurable so I try to calculate it for a duration of a year. Assuming that \{Phi] is w1*t the ratio of the radius after a time of a year and the radius at t=0 is about 8%. The Ratio would be much smaller for shorter times.

Comment: If the equations are without error, you could introduce a new timesscale `t-> \[Tau] /Sqrt[w2]` which gives two differential equations only depending on one parameter `w1/Sqrt[w2]` ...

Comment: I get an error, but I do not get the errors you report.  Are you sure the parameters and code are what you used?  Perhaps it's a version difference.  I'm using 11.3.0.0 (Mac).

Answer (score 1):

What is expected to get as a result of this task? The function $\phi (t)$ is practically linear, the function $r(t)$ is practically constant.

```
modp = {D[r[t]*Cos[\[Phi][t]], {t, 2}] == 
    w1*D[r[t]*Sin[\[Phi][t]], t] - w2*Cos[w1*t]*Sin[\[Phi][t]], 
   D[r[t]*Sin[\[Phi][t]], {t, 2}] == -w1*D[r[t]*Cos[\[Phi][t]], t] - 
     w2*Cos[w1*t]*Cos[\[Phi][t]]};
w1 = 1.52*10^10;
w2 = 0.437; v0 = 7.5*10^7;
sol = NDSolveValue[{modp, r[0] == v0/w1, \[Phi][0] == 0, 
    r'[0] == 0, \[Phi]'[0] == -v0/r[0]}, {r[t], \[Phi][t], 
    r'[t], \[Phi]'[t]}, {t, 0, Pi*10^4}];
 {Plot[sol[[1]], {t, 0, Pi*10^4}],
 Plot[sol[[2]], {t, 0, Pi*10^4}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I expect. r(t) describes the radius of the motion of an electron induced by a magnetic field and a small modification so I don't expect it to Change by a large ammount. Can you tell me the main difference between NDSolve and NDSolveValue ?

Comment: Using NDSolveValue, we get a solution in the form of an interpolation function, so we can use it directly, like any function.

Comment: Nice solution but you used only `1/1000` of the timerange (OP)

Comment: For the original range I get warnings again but by increasing the MaxSteps und decreasing the MaxStepSize they vanish. Seems like the Change of r(t) is really negligible even for such huge time Intervalls.

Comment: Yes, I got a solution up to $t=\pi *10^4$, but I did not see anything significant - almost a constant and a linear function. What can you expect more?